# How to access Qt's resource file in the c++ project?

Tags: c++, qt, audio

I have added a alert.wav sound file to the .qrc file. 
Then I qmake the project to generate a VS project.

I can actually see the alert.wav file in the solution explorer.
Now the problem is to play this alert.wav file using windows's default API.

I have tried this:

```
PlaySound(L"alert.wav", NULL, SND_RESOURCE | SND_ASYNC | SND_NOSTOP);
```

and this:

```
PlaySound(L":files/sound/alert.wav", NULL, SND_RESOURCE | SND_ASYNC | SND_NOSTOP);
```

But none of them works, I can actually play through the QSound by passing in ":files/sound/alert.wav".
How could I play it through PlaySound? The only way I know is to play it as a file on the system, but that's not what I need.

Comment: Only Qt objects and functions can access qt resources. I don't know is it possible for `PlaySound`, but for other cases I usually load file to QByteArray and then use data from memory with WinAPI functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly use the ressource file, since only `QFile` (ohter Qt-Classes) are aware of these ressources. To play it, you will need to create a local copy:

```
QString path = QDir::temp().absoluteFilePath("alert_tmp.wav");//a path in the temporary folder
QFile::copy(":files/sound/alert.wav", path);//Will return true if copied, false if the target already exists
PlaySound((wchar_t*)path.utf16(), NULL, SND_RESOURCE | SND_ASYNC | SND_NOSTOP);
```

Please note that you may have collisions in the temporary folder. You can use a custom sub-directory to avoid this.
Whats useful about this approach is the fact that the file will only be copied if it does not already exist in the temporary folder, and will just be copied again if the user e.g. deletes all temporary files.

**HINT:**
If you just want to play a sound, [`QSound`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsound.html) may work for you. It too does not support resources (for now), but may be easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RCC>
 <qresource prefix="/files">
        <file alias="alert">sounds/alert.wav</file>
 </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Does your .qrc file look like this ? You should try ":files/alert" (`prefix/alias`).

I can not help you more, I never use PlaySound.

Answer (score 1):

I think this way is more paradigmatic, as you get a safe, RAII style temporary file. This is good for a "first-call" scenario where you want to cache the data for subsequent, repeat calls.

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QTemporaryFile>

void do_something(const QString& resource)
{
    QFile file(resource);
    auto temporary_file = QTemporaryFile::createNativeFile(file);
    auto full_path = temporary_file->fileName();
    auto full_path_wstring = full_path.toStdWString();
    do_something(full_path_wstring);
}
```